# pandas pivot data Cols to rows and rows to cols

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I am using python and pandas have tried a variety of attempts to pivot the following (switch the row and columns)

Example:
A is unique

```
         A       B   C   D     E... (and so on)
     [0] apple   2   22  222
     [1] peach   3   33  333
     [N] ... and so on
```

And I would like to see

```
    ?  ?       ?     ?   ... and so on
    A  apple   peach
    B  2       3
    C  22      33
    D  222     333
    E 
    ... and so on
```

I am ok if the columns are named after the col "A", and if the first column needs a name, lets call it "name"

```
    name  apple   peach ...
    B     2       3
    C     22      33
    D     222     333
    E 
    ... and so on
```

Comment: Have you tried df.T where df is the DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you're wanting [transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) here.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 'apple', 1: 'peach'}, 'B': {0: 2, 1: 3}, 'C': {0: 22, 1: 33}})

df = df.T

print(df)

     0       1
A   apple   peach
B   2       3
C   22      33
```

Edit for comment. I would probably reset the index and then use the df.columns to update the column names with a list. You may want to reset the index again at the end as needed.

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

df.columns = ['name', 'apple', 'peach']

df = df.iloc[1:, :]

print(df)

    name    apple   peach
1   B       2       3
2   C       22      33
```

Comment: thank you! and if I wanted the column name to be the value in "A" ?

Comment: See update based upon your comment. Let me know if you need anything further.

Answer (score 0):

try `df.transpose()` it should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Taking the advice from the other posts, and a few other tweaks (explained in line) here is what worked for me.

```
    # get the key column that will become the column names.
    # add the column name for the existing columns

    cols = df['A'].tolist()
    cols.append('name')

    # Transform
    df = df.T
    
    # the transform takes the column, and makes it an index column.
    # need to add it back into the data set (you might want to drop 
    # the index later to get rid if it all together)
    df['name'] = df.index

    # now to rebuild the columns and move the new "name" column to the first col
    df.columns = cols
    cols = df.columns.tolist()
    cols = cols[-1:] + cols[:-1]
    df = df[cols]

    # remove the row, (was the column we used for the column names
    df = df.iloc[1:, :]
```